# how to pass arguments to a class when initializing a thread?

Tags: python

I'm trying to call the number of classes equal to the number of rows in the table and pass the argument there. but i get an error

```
NameError: name 'iterr' is not defined. Did you mean: 'iter'?

class App(iterr):
   def __init__(self):


if __name__ == '__main__':
table = open('config/url.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')
table_url = ''
for u in table:
    table_url = u
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='config/auth.json')
sh = gc.open_by_url(table_url)
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
values_list = worksheet.col_values(1)
threads = len(values_list)
i = 1
while i < threads+1:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=App, args=(i,))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Your error is due to a typo

Comment: class App(XXX) means that App class is inheriting properties from class named XXX -> classApp(): def __init__(self, NAME) means you pass a variable to the constructor of the class named XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass your arguments on the init function.

```
class App():
   def __init__(self, iterr):
```

Comment: yes if it is inheriting but the title says passing arguments, so if inheriting I agree with you if passing arguments to the class then using Init function.